# Ошибка: невозможно неявно преобразовать тип 'string' в 'int'

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Error: cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

Код (изначально):

```
int posib = trackBar1.Value;
```

Код (переделал в):

```
int posib = textBox4.Text; // отсюда берется число. если написать на форме 20, значит для программы означает 20% т.е. указывается число без знака процента
```

Answer (score 0):

`int posib = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);`